# angular - ui grid shows data only if I type in something on the filter field, but data gets bind to the grid though

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, grid

**Here's is my GRID div code - the div gets visible if data is returned**

```
<div ng-if="showDiv" class="col-sm-12 ocdspacing">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">      
                <span><button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="ShowReasonDialog()">Reason Code</button></span>          
                <div ui-grid="gridMEE" class="table text-center" ui-grid-grouping ui-grid-selection ui-grid-auto-resize></div>
            </div></div>
```

**Here's is my binding function -**

```
$scope.GetCustomerData = function (custno) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'MenuExpansionOpportunityExclusions.aspx/GetCustomerData',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: "{" + "strCustomerCD" + ": '" + custno + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $scope.gridMEE.data = JSON.parse(data.d);
                        console.log(data);
                        if (data.d == null) {
                            $scope.showDiv = false;
                        }
                        else {
                            $scope.showDiv = true;
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        $scope.showDiv = false;
                    }
                });
            };
```

The issue is that..the grid binds the data.. but shows only if any type event is fired, suppose I type something in a text box..then only it shows the data..please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change ng-if to ng-show.
It is possible that ng-if creates a new scope and your data does not propagate correctly.

EDIT:
I cannot add a comment, because of low reputation, but this is follow-up to your found solution.
You should use $html or $q/$resource services to send requests.
Since, You are building angular app, it's recommended to use angular services.
$html service would serve you well in this example, and possibly will save some time and bugs in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. As I am using $.ajax function, I should use $scope.$apply() to let angular to update the scope.